# SPI tool error recently - outputs cyan graph instead of blue and red

Tags: r

Hi I've been using the same code for a long time which calls the SPI tool to make a graph. Very recently it started outputting graphs colored completely cyan instead of the blue (positive) and red (negative) colors which it's supposed to use. Anyone else encounter this or have any possible solutions?

Sorry I've never asked a question here before...

```
#sample data
RFt<-as.numeric(sample(1:50, size = 100, replace=T))

#plot spi - this outputs a cyan plot for me
plot(spi(ts(RF,freq=12,start=c(1920,1)),scale = 12,distribution = 'Gamma'))
```